# Number of derangements of of 8 distinct objects

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently doing this two part question and I am confused about the second part, can someone help explain how to do it?

**Part a)**

How many derangements of $$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 $$ ***start with 1,2,3, and 4*** in some order?

My answer: I believe it is 81 because 1-4 have 9 derangements according to the Inclusion Exclusion formula and 5-8 also have 9 derangements so it's simply 9*9 = 81.

**Part b)**

How many derangements with ***5,6,7, and 8*** in some order?

My answer: I wrote it was 81 as well, but apparently I am wrong, can someone explain to me why the answer is $$(4!)^2$$

I just can't seem to understand what the difference is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean "how many derrangements starting with 5, 6, 7, and 8".

Every sequence that starts with those 4 values is a derangement.  So all you are doing is counting how many sequences there are total, which is 4! for the first half and 4! for the second half.

Comment: OHHHHHH.....damn, it makes more sense now since I thought we had to make derangements of them through indices 5 - 8. I see why it's 4! now haha.. 4 for first slot, 3 for second slot and so on.